# Set tab size in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

For some reason, on a document I have, the size of a tab has been reduced to almost nothing. This means that it is hard to determine the indentation level of a line. Is there anyway to change the sizes of the tabs for this section of the document?

Answer (score 53):

Right-click on your document and then click "Paragraph".

Click the "Tabs..." button (bottom left).

Then change the "Default tab stops" (top right).

Answer (score 8):

If you want to set the size of a tab as a certain number of spaces then Microsoft Word 2010 doesn't do it.

Comment: Of course, why would it?

Comment: @samis Because programmers too write reports, and those may include code samples?

Comment: which are using a fixed-pitch font, where it actually makes sense, like in an IDE?

Comment: Yeah I am a programmer and copy pasting a code snippet in Word doc with really long tabs size spills moderately long code line to spill on next line ... I really dont believe this cannot be configured in Word!!!